# MapView ist abstract - cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mapsforge

I'm actually trying to show a map in an app, built with Android Studio.
I use the Library "mapsforge" (https://github.com/mapsforge)
At creating a map view instance I get an error.

I integrated the following libs:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-core:[0.11.0]'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map:[0.11.0]'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-reader:[0.11.0]'
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-themes:[0.11.0]'
implementation 'net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0'
```

And in MainActivity:

```
import org.mapsforge.map.view.MapView;
```

My whole OnCreate:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AndroidGraphicFactory.createInstance(getApplication());
    mapView = new MapView(this);

    mapView.setClickable(true);
    mapView.getMapScaleBar().setVisible(false);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    mapView.setZoomLevelMin((byte) 2);
    mapView.setZoomLevelMax((byte) 10);

    mapView.setZoomLevel((byte) 2);
      mapView.getModel().displayModel.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(t his, R.color.mapBackground));
}
}
```

Throws:
    MapView is abstract - cannot be instantiated.

Sry new in Java

Thanks in advance

Comment: they are using differnt import in the example code: `import org.mapsforge.map.android.view.MapView;`

Comment: Thanks for your help! But it just says: "Unused import statement" and "android" is red marked.

Answer (score 0):

To use the MapView in Android you need to add the Android implementation to your gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:[CURRENT-VERSION]'
implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.4'
```

see the integration guide from their repository: https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Integration.md